# Why is this code giving 32 for the bits in a number (and not 53)?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code to try to find out how many bits are in a number. The hex number below has all bits turned on.

```
for (var i = 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFF, m = 0; i & 1; ++m, i >>>= 1);
```

For some reason printing `m` gives 32, but in a SO post I read the following:

> All numbers in JavaScript are actually IEEE-754 compliant floating-point doubles. These have a 53-bit mantissa which should mean that any integer value with a magnitude of approximately 9 quadrillion or less will be represented accurately.

Unless I'm implementing this incorrectly, I don't understand why printing `m` gives 32 when there are supposed to be 53 bits. Can someone please explain?

Comment: I don't see exactly what your code accomplishes. Even if this worked for numbers of any size, if your `i` is something with a binary representation like `111...1110`, you'd end up with `m = 0`

Comment: @NullUserException How is that so?

Comment: Any 0 in the binary representation would cause the loop to abort immediately. So if your binary ends in 0, the loop ends with the first iteration.

Comment: @NullUserException But that's why I made sure all the bits were turned on. I'm not trying to implement this for any arbitrary integer, this is just a test case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bitwise operations are specified by the JavaScript/ECMAScript standard to truncate the number to 31 bits (round towards zero, take the modulus with 2<sup>32</sup>, and interpret the most significant bit as a two's-complement sign) before anything else happens. So you need to recode it using plain arithmetic.

This is in part because FPUs which handle fractional numbers may not implement bitwise operations, at the logic circuit level.

The most naive way of testing is `for ( var i = 0; i != i + 1; ++ i ) ;` but that crashed Firefox when I tried it. (Was expecting a timeout, but nope!) The slightly more specific one-liner

```
for ( var i = 1, j = 0; i != i + 1; i *= 2, ++ j ) ;
```

does yield `j == 53`.

As an aside, note that the idiom `x | 0` for rounding doesn't work with numbers greater or equal to 2<sup>31</sup>. So `Math.round` is generally better.

Comment: I like your answer because you explain the benefit:  performance by avoiding functionality not provided by the FPU.

Comment: @dsh Is JavaScript used in any performance critical application where this would even matter?

Comment: @NullUserException I saw some cases, but in those cases usually stuff like NACL or asm.js were used. In native JavaScript people usually use typed UInt arrays for when needing more 'integer' operations.

Comment: @NullUserException Sure: consider that JavaScript was created in 1995 when the Pentium was new and now is used extensively on mobile devices where power consumption is important.  Servers built with Node.js are a more recent development.  Honestly, I haven't used bit shift much in my work, and working with JavaScript only recently didn't know this but found the answer to be useful.

Answer (score 5):

Bitwise operation as `>>>` work on 32 bits numbers so `i` gets actually converted to 32bits. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) for more information.

From the [speficication](http://es5.github.com/#x11.7.3):

The production ShiftExpression : ShiftExpression >>> AdditiveExpression is evaluated as follows:

> The Unsigned Right Shift Operator ( >>> )
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
> 4. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 5. Let lnum be **ToUint32(lval)**.
> 6. Let rnum be **ToUint32(rval)**.
> 7. Let shiftCount be the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits of rnum  that is, compute rnum & 0x1F.
> 8. Return the result of performing a zero-filling right shift of lnum by shiftCount bits. Vacated bits are filled with zero. The result is an unsigned 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 0):

The bitwise operators in Javascript work on 32 bit integers.

That means that the floating point number in `i` is converted to a 32 bit integer to be used in the shift operation, and the rest of the bits are discarded.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

> "The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit
>   integers"